# PHP Script CronJob

Tags: php, cron, jobs

I have a script which updates my database of stores. This script when is run from a `CronJob` it stops without errors while processing different stores. If I execute the script via `SSH`, it works perfectly and finishes the job.

What I have tried so far:

1. Setting Time Limit To 0
2. Process stores by giving range parameter to the script for example 0-100
3. I lowered the number of rows I process in every loop
4. I am using `flush()` in every loop and `ob_flush()`

I need this to execute via `CronJob` and to not stop unexpectedly. I know the code works because on SSH it finishes everything after a couple of hours.

Comment: Are there any environments variables used by the script?

Comment: @iamnoten nope! it’s just a script that process the MySQL database using PDO connection

Comment: In your cronjob, add this at the end: `>/tmp/output1 2>/tmp/output2`.  This will show you the stdout and stderr of your script when it runs under cron.  Remember that cron starts an sh shell to run your script, without any environment set.  Also check the cron logs.  Final comment, does the user used in cron the same as when you start it manually?

Comment: @Nic3500 I am using it and there is no error. It’s just my output.

Comment: @shadvein Generally, a script running successfully in shell but not in cron job is caused by environment variables like path ... or user permissions.

Comment: @iamnoten Yes but I don’t get it. It executes and it stops at a different process every time! Do I have permission for like two hours and then my script stops running?